# Another Nim's Game Variant

Tags: algorithm

Given N binary sequence

Example :
given one sequence 101001 means

player 0 can only choose a position with 0 element and remove the sequence from that position resulting  {1 if he choose 2nd element  or 101 if he choose 4nd element or 1010  if he choose 5th element}

player 1 can only choose a position with 1 element ans remove the sequence from that position resulting {null if he choose 1st element or 10 if he choose 3rd element or 10100 if he choose 6th element}

now player 0 and player 1 take turn reducing N sequence, on each turn they pick one sequence, pick an element and remove from that position the the end of the chosen sequence, if a player can't make a move, he lose.

Assume both player play optimally, who will win ?

I tried to solve this problem with grundy but i'm unable to reduce the sequence to a grundy number because it both player don't have the same option to move. Can anyone give me a hint to solve this problem ?

btw sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can sequence start with zero or zeroes?

Comment: yes, if not it will be too easy :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Nim. This is the game of [Blue-red Hackenbush](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-partizan3). There's even an [online hackenbush calculator](http://math.ucsd.edu/~wgarner/math168a/blueredhackenbush.htm) which could solve this specific case (just change B and R to 0 and 1), along with this short explanation of the algorithm:

> Until a color change, each segment is worth +1 or -1 (depending on whether it is Blue or Red, respectively).
>   Once a color change occurs, each subsequent segment (regardless of color), is worth half of the previous segment, with a +/- corresponding to the color.
>   Thus, the string BBRB would be worth +1+1-1/2+1/4=7/4.

So you can compute the value of each sequence. (Let's suppose player 0 is assigned to the positive side, that is, "0" evaluates to +1.) If the sum of these values over all sequences is positive, then player 0 wins. If it's negative, player 1 wins. And if it's 0, then whoever move first loses.

Comment: so if the total value of all sequence is positive, player 0 win, if total value of all sequence is negative, player 1 win, else the first player who make a move lose ? am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is my second try
if player X found X at the top of the stack or list X------- he will take it resulting an empty list that it will leave no moves to the other player and X will win
If Player X found Y at as the first element of the list he will lose any way because what ever he choose on the next turn the player Y will take the first element leaving the Player X with empty list and X will lose
like

```
YXXXXXXXX
```

if player X chose any X from the list, Y will select the first and win.

Did I get your point or not Yet

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem, i just edited by question, just tell me if it's still not clear

Comment: @TerrySmith I updated the answer, Please tell me if i got you point or not yet

Comment: it seems this is the Hackenbush game, thanks for trying to help though :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: as pointed out following is not an optimal solution.

IMO if there is only one sequence, then the Player whose number starts the sequence shall win the game. This is because at his/her turn, he/she will simply remove the first element resulting in NULL string and so no move for the other player.

For multiple sequences I can't find a better optimal strategy than following:

Now let us assume there are m sequences that start with 1 and k sequences that start with 0. Each player's strategy shall be to quickly finish the other player's winning sequences.

Hence Player 0 shall choose the first zero in the m sequences beginning with 1 and Player 1 shall choose the first one in the k sequences beginning with 0.

The player looses whose winning sequence finishes first.

Comment: i have though about that but by choosing it greedily, i don't think it's optimal

Comment: For multiple sequences, if you have more moves in a sequence / prefix of a sequence that the opponent, there might be a better move than removing the entire sequence. For example, if one of the sequences is `1110...`, it would be better to remove the third `1`, as there'd still remain 2 moves for that sequence for `1`. My guess is that the best move is somewhere between the first move in a sequence where you have the most moves and cutting off such a sequence of the opponent.